# Exclude all transitive dependencies of all dependencies?

Tags: java, maven-2

I am working on a maven project and i need to exclude all transitive dependencies. I have seen the "exclude"tag that is used inside "dependency"tag. But i have a lot of dependencies and writing this tag in every dependency is a huge task. So there is any method where i can exclude all transitive dependencies in a much easier way?

Comment: What you are trying is very useless?!

Comment: Is your project going to be able to run without all its dependencies?

Comment: @khelwood .Sometimes we need to include a dependency to use its only one class of it. So we might not to include all its Transitive dependencies.. That's my case!!

Answer (score 3):

[Ever since Maven 3.2.1](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html), you can use wildcards in dependency exclusions.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

You will still have to insert the wildcard exclusion into every single dependency though.

---

Here's an example pom with a Groovy script (executed through the [Groovy Maven Plugin](https://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin/)) that excludes all transitive dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>non-transitive-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>exclude-transitive-deps</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>
                                def exclusion = new org.apache.maven.model.Exclusion();
                                exclusion.groupId='*'
                                exclusion.artifactId='*'
                                project.dependencies.each{
                                    d -> d.addExclusion(exclusion)
                                }
                            </source>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Output for `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ non-transitive-deps ---
[INFO] org.test:non-transitive-deps:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
```

Output for `mvn validate dependency:tree`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ non-transitive-deps ---
[INFO] org.test:non-transitive-deps:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
```

So while this groovy script solves your problem, it only does so when a Maven lifecycle phase is executed (not when you trigger a plugin goal directly). `validate` is the earliest stage in the lifecycle, long before dependency resolution takes place.

And no, I am not aware of any less verbose solution.

Comment: Thanks @Sean Patrick Floyd.  I have seen this before. I'm using large amount of dependencies, so introducing "exclusion" tag in every dependency is a massive effort. Even if i do that, in future, if someone else add a new dependency and forgot to use exclude tag all transitive dependencies of that will be imported.. Right? So all i'm asking is that is there is any way by which we can exclude all the transitive dependencies of all dependencies we are using by default?

Comment: @vineeth I hear you and I share the pain. No, such a mechanism does not exist. The next best thing would be to have a check somewhere in the build process that makes sure that every single dependency has such an exclusions tag and fails the build otherwise. I'd probably do that with a few lines of groovy using the [groovy maven plugin](https://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Is any way by which we put the only needed dependencies as well as transitive dependencies to the local repository and block maven build to access remote repository? I mean maven build should access only our local repository to fetch transitive dependencies.? @Sean

Comment: Thanks for your valuable effort and time.. i have tried the same with a sample project... But transitive dependencies got added and when i tried the same with "exclude" tag, transitive dependencies got removed. So what might be i missed when i tried Groovy??